# How to prevent duplicate database entries while preserving efficiency and application integrity?

Tags: python

I am currently developing an application that has to process a lot of data and stumbled upon a relatively huge data storage problem for me.

I essentially have an enormous list of pairs, e.g. (for simplicity) [(A,B), ..., (A,Z), (B,A), ...], where (B,A) is the inverse of (A,B).

The application now loops over the list of pairs and analyzes the data associated with each pair. This is where the problem arises. The analysis of (A,B) would essentially yield the same result as the analysis of (B,A), and therefore execute the same action on each pair after analysis.

In my mind, this leads to exactly two potential scenarios:

#### Scenario A: I keep (A,B) and remove (B,A).

> **Problem:** I can no longer look up certain values. There is also a possibility that (A,B) is an invalid pair on certain operations, while (B,A) would be acceptable.
>
> **Thoughts:** This is my preferred way of operation, but I do not know how I can ensure that (A,B) will yield the same result as (B,A) without running the whole analysis on both.

#### Scenario B: I keep (A,B) and (B,A).

> **Problem:** If I keep (A,B) and (B,A), this would also mean I would keep (A,C) and (C,A) etc., which would lead to a massive increase/bloat in data to store and process, duplicate API calls, other server requests etc.
>
> **Thoughts:** This option is unacceptable due to certain restrictions on e.g. limited API calls.

I know that this whole problem is very theoretical, because I cannot post any code fragments to visualize it, but I would appreciate any thoughts on this problem - regardless of an attempt to solve it. If you have dealt with an issue like this in the past, I would be glad to hear from you, too.

Also, I have tried looking up solutions, but as you can probably extract from the title and phrasing of this post, I maybe just do not know how to express this problem. If there are certain threads on StackOverflow or bits of information elsewhere, I am happy to consider them.

Thank you for your time!

Best regards

Comment: I would create a convert function, which would translate ```(A,B)``` and ```(B,A)``` to the same value, for any ```A``` and ```B```. (For instance sort element-wise, if ```A``` and ```B``` are both strings, or numbers)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Grzegorz. This indeed would be a practical solution to most of the problem, but the data associated to each pair is huge and selective calculation on a specific subset is not possible, because every data point is relevant. I have tried breaking it up, so subsets can be used on specific tasks, but it really comes down to a lot of inter-class recalculations and overall slow-down.

Comment: Ah, so you want to merge it together somehow, so ```(A,B)``` will become one row with ```(B,A)```? Maybe also a follow up- how do you intend to keep this data in python - ```pandas```, ```dask```, ```pyspark``` ?

Comment: The maximum space saving of scenario a is 50%.  Are you sure it's worth the added complication?  A simple hybrid scenario would be to store (A, B) and have a boolean database column called "reverse" which indicates that (B, A) should also be analysed.